# From jQuery to Prototype/Scriptaculous - hiding and showing divs?

Tags: jquery, html, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I used this example to hide and show some divs on my site:

http://papermashup.com/simple-jquery-showhide-div/

How would I write that using Prototype/Scriptaculous? As I saw they also have show and hide methods?

Thans for helping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('button_id').observe('click', function() {
    Effect.toggle('div_id', 'blind');
});
```